# Rotation of third degree polynomial

Tags: polynomials

If you rotate a third degree polynomial $Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D=0$ through $90^\circ$,  how do you calculate the new values of $A,B,C,D$?

Comment: What does rotate through 90 degrees mean here? Multiply $x$ by $i$? Then replace $x$ by $ix$ and see what you get.

Comment: do you know whats matrix rotation ?

Comment: I use the "Linest" function in excel to fit data to the polynomial. Linest gives me a polynomial with coefficients A,B,C,D. The data to be fitted is in the form of x,y coordinates. If I rotate these coordinates through any angle using the rotation matrix and fit the data again, Linest gives me new coefficients of X^3, x^2 etc. The question is how to calculate these coefficients manually for any rotation angle?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really mean to rotate the graph of $y=Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$ by $90^\circ$?  This will be the graph of $-x=Ay^3+By^2+Cy+D$, but it is not guaranteed to be a function-it may well fail the vertical line test.  You can then solve this for $y$ as a function of $x$ using the [Cardano solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) but it is a fair mess.

Comment: I use 3rd degree polynomials to model the offsets of clothoids. I use the Linest function in Excel to this end. If the clothoid is pointing almost due north, Linest gives the wrong information with the start of the curve beginning 5 to 10 meters above where it should start. I then assume the curve is rotated 90 degree (West or East) and calculate coordinates for this direction. Once the coordinates have been calculated I recalculate them for North using the rotation matrix.